# Primary key is not loaded from PostgreSQL to JTable

Tags: java, postgresql, swing, netbeans, jtable

I'm new to PostgreSQL and Java Swing.

In PostgreSQL `company` database, I have a `users` table and it has 4 fields: user_id, username, phone, and address.

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    user_id    serial primary key,
    username   VARCHAR(40) not null,
    phone      VARCHAR(14) not null,
    address    VARCHAR(50)
);
```

I'm trying to load all fields from `users` table to `JTable` in Java Swing using Bound (Figure 1).
Then I bind the elements from the table (Figure 2).

As you can see in Figure 2, it shows only 3 fields except `user_id`. I need to load this `user_id` field as well because I need to perform CRUD data.

How can I achieve that?

[image: Figure 1]
[image: Figure 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the solution.

When I import the data from the database to the form, the Model (for example; Users.java) file is generated.
The problem was I firstly generated that file and later I added the `user_id` column to the database, so guess what, the Model file is somehow not updated and so the `user_id` is not there.

Therefore, I had manually added getter and setter for the `user_id` field, and now ok.